# How to show custom post type in all post section?

Tags: plugins, posts, customization

I want to show my custom post type live-blog in the all post listing page ie. http://www.wordpress.com:8080/wp-admin/edit.php

So for that i am using pre_get_posts hook in order to show live-blog and posts together on that page.

```
function show_custom_post_type_in_listing($query) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_feed() ) {
            $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'live-blog'));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_custom_post_type_in_listing');
```

This works well in listing the live-blog in all posts section but it breaks when i filter the posts on the basis of category.

My URL becomes

http://www.wordpress.com:8080/wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=Array&_wpnonce=52e69e14a7&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fs%26post_status%3Dall%26post_type%3Dpost%26action%3D-1%26m%3D0%26cat%3D15%26post_format%26seo_filter%26readability_filter%26filter_action%3DFilter%26paged%3D1%26action2%3D-1&action=-1&m=0&cat=15&post_format=&seo_filter=&readability_filter=&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1

Here post_type is set to Array which gives invalid post type.

Is there any way to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty hacky, but this does work in my testing (I tested with built-in `page` post type):

```php
// Change the post list and search query.
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', static function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! in_array( $query->get( 'post_type' ), array( 'post', 'Array' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
} );

// If `post_type` is set to `Array`, change back to `post` to satisfy core validation.
add_action( 'admin_init', static function () {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['s'] ) || '/wp-admin/edit.php' !== $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] || ! isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || 'Array' !== $_GET['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    $_GET['post_type'] = 'post';
    $_REQUEST['post_type'] = 'post';
} );
```

The main functional piece here is checking the `$_GET['post_type']` value on the `admin_init` action, and if it's equal to `Array`, then change it to `post` (to satisfy WP core). Then when the query is actually constructed, change the `post_type` parameter to both post types.

Comment: It really works like a magic but whenever i use seo plugin like rank or yoast and i filter through the SEO scores it works well for the first time but gives invalid post type for second time

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem: you can't possibly support every plugin in existence. Some plugins might give you an option to adjust their queries, but not all.

Comment: Is there any way just to provide rank math and yoast

Comment: You'll have to look into those plugins and see what options they provide for their sorting/searching.

Comment: Can you please provide some help into it

Comment: Probably best to post a new question, but not on this site, as this site is not for themes/plugins support.

Comment: Where can i post the question for you

Comment: One last thing I did this 

add_action( 'admin_init', static function () {

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['s'] ) || '/wp-admin/edit.php' !== $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] || ! isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) || 'Array' !== $_GET['post_type']) {
        $_GET['post_type'] = 'post';
        $_REQUEST['post_type'] = 'post';
    }

    // $_GET['post_type'] = 'post';
    // $_REQUEST['post_type'] = 'post';
} );

and this worked well for me

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're setting the `post_type` query var to an array. While this works for most query purposes, it's not compatible with the admin post filtering links.

The `pre_get_posts` hook affects all queries on the site, not just the main query. By checking `is_main_query()`, you are only modifying the main query, but the filtering in the admin happens in a secondary query.

What you could do is further limit the scope of your `pre_get_posts` modification. You might check if the query is an admin query, and then further check if the post type is 'post'.

Here's an updated version of your function that should work:

```
function show_custom_post_type_in_listing($query) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') === 'post' ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'live-blog'));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_custom_post_type_in_listing');
```

This will only modify the main query on the post list in the admin when the post type is '**post**', adding your custom post type to the query.

Remember to refresh your permalinks by visiting **Settings** → **Permalinks** in your WordPress dashboard after making changes to the query structure.

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't improve anything: the search still breaks. The explanation is correct, but the new code has the same problem.